# Changing the active tab in material-ui from default pink to some other color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is the codesandbox link where we need to change the active tab color. 
[Code sample here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3ql9xzr6oq)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new indicator class in your styles

```
indicator: {
  backgroundColor: "green"
}
```

and then override the indicator class in your `Tabs` component

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} classes={{ indicator: classes.indicator }}>
```